# How to get elastic search to play with MongoDb and node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am fairly new to both mongodb and node.js but recently got everything to work well for me until I reached the point where I needed to add a full text search to my website. From my research I figured out that Elasticsearch would be a good fit, but I couldnt figure out exactly how to get it to work with node.js and mongodb. I am currently using Heroku and MongoLab to host my application. Here are  my questions.

1. How do I host Elasticsearch?
2. How do I make all my mongo data available to elasticsearch do I use a river or do I manually inset and delete all data?

   I found something this [river](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb) but I am not quite sure how to make this happen automatically and where to host it.
3. How do I query Elasticsearch from node.js? Is there a package that allows for this?

Edit:

Question 2 is really what I am struggling with. I have also included question 1 and 3 to help people that are new to the topic and coming from google.

Comment: No offence but this seems like a set of questions whose answers could be easily garnished by reading the first page of the documentation for ElasticSearch use with MongoDB; I mean "How do I host Elasticsearch?"...

Comment: Yes question 2 is probably the only one that is hard to answer I added the other two just to help out other people looking to start.

Comment: I use ElasticSearch 0.9.11 on large EC2 Instance + MongoDB 2.4.9 replica set on two high-memory EC2 instances and it works fantastic. Lots of inserts, lots of updates, and lots of deletes per second and no way you can do it as smooth and seamless as MongoDB-river you mentioned by using anything else. It looks after your oplogs. Btw, manually?! You kidding right? If you have documents pretty much static just sitting there in MongoDB don't bother make the connection just insert the index automatically into ElasticSearch. The river helps to automate these transactions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) either on your own server/VM/whatever.. or with a hosted service such as https://searchbox.io/

2) you can create a script to index your existing data and then index new data once its created, or use a river to index your current database.

3) ElasticSearch is a simple HTTP API, you can make your own requests using the 'http' module or simplify it with something like https://github.com/mikeal/request

you can also use a 3rd party library like https://github.com/phillro/node-elasticsearch-client

Answer (score 1):

Searchly.com (Aka SearchBox.io)introduced a new feature crawlers includes MongoDB crawler.
It fetches data from a given collection and syncs periodically to ElasticSearch. Check http://www.searchly.com/documentation/crawler-beta/

Answer (score 0):

1. You can host on your own server or use aws elasticsearch service or use elastic cloud provided by elasticsearch.
2. Try any of the following three solutions:-
          i) Try using mongoosastic. NPM package
         ii) Use mongo-connector.
         iii) python script for indexing data to elasticsearch
3. elasticsearch-js. The  javascript client library